# How to access "config.php" variables in "course/renderer.php" script moodle 2.8?

Tags: php, moodle

I am using moodle 2.8.

I wants to add few lines of code in "course/renderer.php" script and also wants to use config variables in that script. I tried this by simply

require_once("../config.php")

but I am not getting config variables.

Thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

By the time your code executes, config.php will already have been loaded.

The Moodle Way™ is to pull in the global $CFG object to access those properties.

```
function wotsit() {
    global $CFG;
    echo $CFG->config_value;
}
```